# "Workbook BeforePrint" Not Firing

Tags: vba, excel

UPDATED:

Of all the things that I tried, printing this simplified workbook was not one of them. The BeforePrint does fire, however, only after the preview pane and clicking print does the message box appear.

It was my understanding that one should be able to preview the change before printing actually occurs. Am I wrong?

---

I am using Excel 2016. I am trying to get my header to obtain the value in A1 and have found examples of doing this. However, I have not had any luck in getting the BeforePrint Event to work.

My Original Code (The way I wanted it)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Troubleshooting that I have tried:

1. Started a brand new workbook so that nothing could be wrong with the one that I was attempting to add this function to.
2. Just make a simple message box appear instead of doing something more complicated.
3. Attempted to run other events to make sure I had gotten the thought process of events correct.
4. Design Mode is not on
5. Macros Security is set to allow Macros
6. The sheet has some random letters in one of the cells to allow for editing (Updated per comments)

Below are the three events that I have attempted to troubleshoot my issue. The "BeforeSave" & "Open" Events both work fine.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox "Printing... Maybe..."

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox "Saving..."

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Debug.Print "Running Open"
    MsgBox "Welcome"

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the sheet have anything on it?  You can't print a blank sheet.

Comment: I have changed my question to reflect that there is data on the sheet

Comment: Does the file actually print?

Comment: In Excel 2010, Workbook_BeforePrint does fire on preview but not in 2016.  Undocumented feature maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2013 and later doesn't run Workbook_BeforePrint on Print Preview. However, you can get it to run for testing by adding the 'Print Preview Full Screen' icon to your QAT (Quick Access Toolbar)[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he065.jpg)